# Why does Context return undefined for a Parent component but not its children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, render, react-context

I am able to get the values from Context at one component but not at the other that is its 'parent'.
My Context file:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
const Context = React.createContext()

const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isConfiguring, setIsConfiguring] = useState(false)
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ isConfiguring, setIsConfiguring }}>
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  )}

export { Context, ContextProvider }
```

At the 'Form' component, I wrap the ContextProvider around 'Options'

```
...
return (
   ...
   <ContextProvider>
       <Options />
   </ContextProvider>
   ...
)
```

At 'Options' component I am unable to get destructure the context, as it returns 'undefined'.

```
const Options = () => {
   const { isConfiguring, setIsConfiguring } = useContext(Context) //undefined
//TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'isConfiguring' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.

   const serviceElements = servicesList.map(service =>
         <Service
           name={service.name}
         />)

   return (
      ...
      {serviceElements}
      )
      ...
   )
}
```

Then, to my surprise, Context works inside of 'Service' component (which is inside of 'Options')

```
const Service = (props) => {
   const { isConfiguring } = useContext(Context) //works!!!
}
```

So how can I go about fixing this? At the 'Options' component, I tried doing this:

```
const context = useContext(Context)
  console.log(context) //undefined at first. 
                       //when component renders, it logs '{isConfiguring: false, setIsConfiguring: ƒ}'
```

```
//It will log undefined when the component isn't on my screen (rendering). 
//But when I go to the route where the component is at, it logs as 
{isConfiguring: false, setIsConfiguring: ƒ}
//However, doing 
console.log(context.isConfiguring) //TypeError: Cannot read property 'isConfiguring' of undefined 
//even before the component is rendered.
```

Comment: It looks like you have two different contexts: 1. `useContext(Context)`; 2. `useContext(ContextOptionsEstabelecimento)`? What is the difference and how hierarchy of components (with context providers included) look like?

Comment: @Danko I have now renamed them correctly. They are the same Context (and the problem still exists...). Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Can you temporarily move `ContextProvider` to be a parent of the Router and see if there is any difference? It's just my curiosity..

Comment: @Danko still get the same error

Comment: I've made a [runnable example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1mpgqn) using code you listed. It works just fine as I should, so I guess the problem is not just in how you consume the context. You may remount your `Form` with Provider inside or something like this. What I'm trying to say is that it is hard to say where the problem is without full runnable example of your code.

Comment: I suspect the same, problem might be elsewhere. Are you using other `<Options />` instance without `<ContextProvider />` somewhere? From your description, if error is raised in `<Options />` then the program should've hang up, and `<Service />` will not be rendered thus no log from it should be seen.

Comment: Seems like you have multiple instances of `Options` component inside your App, Please search for `<Options` and see if any instance of Options component is rendered outside of the ContextProvider

Comment: It would have been a lot easier if you can create a reproduce this as an example on some platform. As suggested by @shubham-khatri looks like there are multiple instances of Options component, which are not wrapped with ContextProvider component.

Comment: I'm sorry for dumb question, did you import Context into Options module,
e.g. did you 
`import {Context} from './ThatContext.js';`
before use in
`useContext(Context);`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri any suggestions on how to do that search? I don't think I know how to go about debugging this

Comment: In your Editor, you can search though the directory. Try searching `<Options` you should get a list of all usages. Try navigating through each as see which options instance isn't wrapped by the provider. Also if you aren't restricted to share your Code, you can also share the github repository link if you have one

Comment: Do you have a full working code snapplet? Because I think stepping thou via the dev tools will help. I guess that at some point there is some inheritance from upper variable scopes which makes it work.